# Is Lightning the way forward?

Tags: visualforce, ui, lightning

At this point, when starting with new implementations is it better to go with Lightning Framework for UI and better UX, or to continue with Visualforce based UIs?

Comment: I do not think Lightning is currently in a state that would allow it to be adopted by large enterprise customers. Right now it is in its infancy and has a lot of limitations / bugs. If the entire user base is not on lightning, you will have to double the development to support both LEX and Aloha. At this point I thing for the desktop world it is neat, a novelty, but not grown up yet. Time will tell if it is widely adopted. With than said, it is worthwhile to learn and keep up to date.

Answer (score 3):

this question is answered multiple times here and those answers gives you clear idea when you us what. one of them is here.

[(Why) Should I Use Lightning Apps?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/67690/why-should-i-use-lightning-apps)

Here are some points which i want to put on this question.

1. You don't have to spend your time optimizing your apps for different devices as the components take care of that for you because everything is responsive and follow some guidelines with design system.
2. Performance
     Uses a stateful client and stateless server architecture that relies on
     JavaScript on the client side to manage UI component metadata and
     application data. The client calls the server only when absolutely
     necessary; for example to get more metadata or data. The server only sends
     data that is needed by the user to maximize efficiency. The framework uses
     JSON to exchange data between the server and the client. It intelligently 
     utilizes your server, browser, devices, and network so you can focus on
     the logic and interactions of your apps.
3. Faster development
     Empowers teams to work faster with out-of-the-box components that function
     seamlessly with desktop and mobile devices. Building an app with 
     components facilitates parallel design, improving overall development efficiency.
4. Device-aware and cross browser compatibility
     Apps use responsive design and provide an enjoyable user experience. The
     Lightning Component framework supports the latest in browser technology
     such as HTML5, CSS3, and touch events.

So simple way I would say yes it is lightning way forward.

Comment: Can you explain how to meet the needs of both users that have Lightning Experience enabled and users that don't (including users that are still on IE9 and IE10)?